# how to match nginx location regex of any location that starts with ? (question mark)

Tags: regex, nginx-location

trying to catch requests that starts with ?

[www.mydomain.com/](http://www.mydomain.com/)?

trying using `location ~ /\\? {  }`
but it doesn't catch.
What am I missing ?

to clarify - I need to catch all calls that has ? immediately after the url with the '/' sign.

Answer (score 1):

Locations do not match query strings, so the slash will be the last character in location, therefore you need `location ~ /$`. Then you can check `$args` if you want.